# Necessary condition of optimality for functionals

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, optimization

Let $C(a, b)$ denote the set of all surjective and continuously differentiable functions
$\alpha:[a, b] \rightarrow [a, b]$.

Consider the functional on $C(a, b)$
$$
F[\alpha(t)] = \int_a^b f(\alpha(t))dt,
$$
where $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable (note that I do not want to include the factor $\alpha'(t)$ in the integral). How does the function $\alpha$ looks like that maximizes the functional $F$?

The necessary condition states
$$
f_{\alpha} = 0.
$$
This means that $f$ must be constant as a function of $\alpha$, that is 
$$
f(\alpha(t)) = c.
$$
My questions are as follows:

- Is my argumentation so far correct?
- If so, how should I interpret this? I assume a function $f$ that is not necessarily constant and obtain that a necessary condition for an extremum point is that $\alpha$ can be anything but $f$ must be constant. I would like to have something the other way around. I want that $f$ is anything and would like to have an $\alpha$ that maximizes $F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x) = \max _{t\in [a,b]}f(t)$. If you make $\alpha(t) = x$ for all $t\in [a,b]$, that becomes the optimal solution. Now, since for some reason you want $\alpha$ to be surjective, the latter solution does not work directly, but you can approximate it as close as you want (in the output) with functions $\alpha_\delta$ such that

1. $\alpha_\delta(t) =x$ for all $t\geq a+\delta$
2. $\alpha_\delta([a,a+\delta/2]) = [a,b]$
3. make a smooth connection between $a+\delta/2$ and $a+\delta$.

You'll get that 
$$
  \lim_{\delta\to 0}F[\alpha_\delta] = F[\alpha] = f(x)(b-a).
$$
Your necessary condition is not clear to me.

Comment: Consider the functional $F(\alpha) = \int_a^b (f(\alpha(t)) - c)^2 dt$, where c is a constant. Our goal is to minimize $F$. The necessary condition is that $2(f(\alpha)-c) = 0$ implying $f(\alpha) = c$. The necessary condition that $F$ attains an extremum at $\alpha$ is that the derivative of the integrand w.r.t. $\alpha$ is zero. In this example, everything seems to make sense. In the original example, I am confused. Looking at your examples indicates that the original functional has no maximum and your solution is a supremum. But how do I interpret the necessary condition $f(\alpha) = c$?

Comment: Your original post was about a different functional and a different optimization problem. Would you be consistent, please?

Comment: The comment refers to your statement that the necessary condition is not clear to you.